# Property 'yAxis' does not exist on type 'ExportingButtonsOptionsObject'

Tags: angular, typescript, highcharts

I am using highcharts-angular and typescript and trying to update y-axis type but getting error

> Property 'yAxis' does not exist on type 'ExportingButtonsOptionsObject'

This is the code and getting error on

```
onclick: function () {
            this.yAxis[0].update({
              type: 'linear'
            })
          }
```

Whole code:

```
yAxis: [
      {
        labels: {
            align: 'left'
        },
        height: '80%',
        resize: {
            enabled: true
        }
      }, 
      {
        labels: {
            align: 'left'
        },
        top: '80%',
        height: '20%',
        offset: 0
      }
    ],
    exporting: {
      buttons: {
        contextButton: {
          enabled: false,
          align: 'left',
        },
        customButton: {
          text: 'Linear',
          onclick: function () {
            this.yAxis[0].update({
              type: 'linear'
            })
          }
        },
        customButton2: {
          text: 'Logarithmic',
          onclick: function () {
            this.yAxis[0].update({
              type: 'logarithmic'
            })
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like `this` is not what you think it is. You can try using arrow functions instead, these will help you to capture the right `this`:

```
onclick: () => {
  this.yAxis[0].update({
    type: 'linear'
  })
}
```